# Change to a mapped drive on Windows CMD not working?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to access a network drive on CMD so I can run some commands on it, but it cmd keeps reporting that that the 'system cannot find the drive specified'.

I have tried:

```
Y:
cd /d Y:
```

Both return the same error. When I run `net use Y:` it returns:

```
Local name        Y:
Remote name       \\***.***.**.*\web
Resource type     Disk
The command completed successfully.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: These results are consistent your running `cmd` with administrative privileges, which can't access user shares. If you have access, there are normally a couple more lines in the `net` response.

Answer (score 0):

Found out my issue was running the command prompt as admin. As soon as I ran it normally it worked fine. Must be a user issue.

Comment: You may want to check out some of the solutions when you search for "windows map drive for all users".

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx